# Delete a block including nested braces

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have the following block in an NGINX config file

```
server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /web/default/wwwroot/;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

and I want to delete the entire block.
I have tried with the following sed / regex command;

```
sed -ri '/server,/.*\}/d' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

But it finalises the delete on the first closing brace found and leaves a section beyond.

```
   error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

How I do get it to match on the matching closing brace and delete the whole, block, please!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use addresses to match all lines between pattern 1 and pattern 2, ie `sed '/pattern1/,/pattern2/'`.

In your case, deleting everything from the line starting with `server {` to the line starting with     `}` is written as:

```bsh
sed '/^server {/,/^    }/d' file
```

Comment: note that this is correct for the example, but fragile, it depends on the closing `}` (and ONLY that one) to be indented by the correct amount.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's not *that* fragile. It only requires that the closing brace for `server {` be the first one after `server {` that is indented by that amount.

Comment: @fuzzydrawrings if I wan't to comment the same, instead of deleting, what should I do?

Comment: Got it. `sed '/^server {/,/^    }/  s:.*:// \0:' file` works.  (Used `:` as delimiter instead of `/` to avoid escaping literal `/` used for comments).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, nginx config is not a regular language – you can't guaranteedly parse it using regular expressions, so `sed` might simply not be the tool of choice. In your example, for things to actually work in every case, you'd need to count opening `{` that are not parts of comments, strings, globs... and match them with closing `}` until you found the one matching your `server {`.

Fuzzy Drawing's answer works with your *example*, because it can rely on indentation. Can you guarantee that's gonna be the exact same in every file, and if it isn't, you're willing to misconfigure your server without noticing?

I'd recommend you use something that actually "understands" nginx' config language, parses it, and allows you to modify the result.

Nginx inc. themselves have [`crossplane`](https://github.com/nginxinc/crossplane), which is *exactly* for such purposes. If you know python, you can use the module (and I'd recommend that!), but if you want to stay within a shell:

`crossplane parse` will convert a nginx config file to JSON. `crossplane build` does the inverse. `jq` understands and is able to edit JSON. So,

```
crossplane parse /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | \
  jq 'jq commands that do exactly what you want | \
    crossplane build --stdout - > newconfig.conf
```